# Simple Radio HTML form passing PHP variables on submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to be able to send three variables using an html form using radio option.

So, depending on which radio option is selected, it then needs to post the relevant three variables, of which one is an array. The framework allows the use of three variables only, of which one has to be $option(array)

```
<?php   $onx = 10;
    $onx_eta = "1 day";
    $onx_aw = 3;

    $bud = 8;
    $bud_eta = "2 days";
    $bud_aw = 2;

    $ecc = 6;
    $ecc_eta = "3 days";
    $ecc_aw = 1;

    $qty = 1;
    //$option = array($onx_eta, $onx_aw) //if ONX option is selected
    //$option = array($bud_eta, $bud_aw) //if BUDAIR option selected
    //$option = array($ecc_eta, $ecc_aw) //if ECC option is selected
    ?>

    <h2>HTML Forms</h2>

    <h2>Radio Buttons</h2>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="service" value="onx"> ONX
        <br>
        <!-- if this option is selected it needs to post $onx, $qty, $option -->
        <input type="radio" name="service" value="bud"> BUDAIR
        <br>
        <!-- if this option is selected it needs to post $bud, $qty, $option -->
        <input type="radio" name="service" value="ecc"> ECC
        <br>
        <!-- if this option is selected it needs to post $ecc, $qty, $option -->
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <p>Select which service you require</p>


Welcome <?php echo $_POST["service"]; ?><br>
```

I would then expect to be able to retrieve the three variables once the form has been submitted. The problems that I see are that radio option has to use the same "name=".

Answer (score 0):

You can send some variables while submitting your form if you just add something like that:

```
<form method="POST" action="abc.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="myhiddenvar" value="<?php echo 'some_value'; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done some modification in php & html code. I have submitted the data in `JSON` format, which will be decoded on server side.

```
<?php   
    $qty = 1;
    $service_onx = [
        'service' => 'onx',
        'onx' => 10,
        'qty' => $qty,
        'option' => [
            'onx_eta' => '1 day',
            'onx_aw' => '3'
        ]
    ];

    $service_bud = [
        'service' => 'bud',
        'bud' => 8,
        'qty' => $qty,
        'option' => [
            'bud_eta' => '2 days',
            'bud_aw' => '2'
        ]
    ];

    $service_ecc = [
        'service' => 'ecc',
        'onx' => 6,
        'qty' => $qty,
        'option' => [
            'ecc_eta' => '3 days',
            'ecc_aw' => '1'
        ]
    ];
?>
<h2>HTML Forms</h2>
<h2>Radio Buttons</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="service" value="<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($service_onx));?>"> ONX
    <br>
    <!-- if this option is selected it needs to post $onx, $qty, $option -->
    <input type="radio" name="service" value="<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($service_bud));?>"> BUDAIR
    <br>
    <!-- if this option is selected it needs to post $bud, $qty, $option -->
    <input type="radio" name="service" value="<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($service_ecc));?>"> ECC
    <br>
    <!-- if this option is selected it needs to post $ecc, $qty, $option -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<p>Select which service you require</p>
```

Server side code after form submit

```
if(!empty($_POST['service'])) {
    $service = json_decode($_POST['service'], true);
    switch($service['service']) {
        case 'onx':
            // ...
            break;
        case 'bud':
            // ...
            break;
        case 'ecc':
            // ...
            break;
        default:
            // invaid service
            break;
    }
}
```